# problems with the jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input date where I want the user not to choose dates before the current day I am using the minDate function but by default, the calendar jumps me to the date of november 2027. I hope you can help me, I've been working on this for days.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(function(){
        const fechaAhora= new Date();
        const year=fechaAhora.getFullYear();
        const mes=fechaAhora.getMonth() + 1;
        const dia=fechaAhora.getDate()+ 1;
        const fechaD=year+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;
        $("#fecha").datepicker({
            minDate:fechaD,
        })      
    })
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
minDate: new Date()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it as soon as I get free, you know mother's day.